# ssh using bash script for several nodes

Tags: bash, ssh

I can't seem to get this script to work. I am trying to query the amount of cpu's on a list of nodes in a file.

```
readarray fnames < nodes.txt

for fn in "${fnames[@]}"
do
  com="ssh $fn `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l`"
  com=${com: -2}
  echo $fn                        $com
done
```

It should print the hostname than number of cpu's. Instead it prints the hostname and 8 every time. I suspect the 8 is because of

```
bash: 8: command not found
```

being displayed.

Comment: I noticed it seems to always run the `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l` for the current hostname, which why it always returns 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this :

```
readarray fnames < nodes.txt

for fn in "${fnames[@]}"
do
  echo "getinfo:$fn"
  com="ssh $fn cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l"
  com1=$($com) # or com1=`$com`
  echo "$fn                        $com1"
done
```

Comment: It comes up with `./cpus.sh: line 14: com: command not found` error.

Comment: @JacquesMALAPRADE , is this linux ? what version ?  show listing

Comment: @JacquesMALAPRADE , made change :  com1=$($com)

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 14.04. I managed to get it to work. I will edit it above. Needs to be `com1=backquote$com backquote`